# Javascript: Access object's reference variable

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm not sure if I'm asking this question correctly, but how do I access an object's reference variable?

For example,

```
var datagrid = new DataBaseGrid();
console.log(datagrid);

DatabaseGrid.prototype.initializeGrid = function(grid) {

    var self = this;
    console.log(self); //self references same object as datagrid

    grid.setCellRenderer("action", new CellRenderer({ 
        render: function(cell, id) {                 
              cell.innerHTML+= "<i onclick=\""+self+".deleteRow("+id+");\" class='fa fa-trash-o' ></i>";
              console.log(cell.innerHTML);
        }
    })); 
};
```

For cell.innerHTML, I want to replace `self` with the object reference, `datagrid`. So the cell's HTML will render as the following if `id` is 55:

```
<i onclick="datagrid.deleteRow("55")"; class='fa fa-trash-o' ></i>
```

Instead, I'm getting an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (index):1` when clicking on that element.

The reason why I want to do this is because I have other DataBaseGrid objects that will use initializeGrid, and I don't want to hard-code only one object reference to it.

Comment: You are trying to convert an object reference to a string. That can't work. Use one of the other ways to bind an event handler.

Comment: That `<i>` is neither keyboard nor screen reader accessible. To fix keyboard, make it a real `<button>`. To fix screen reader, you need some sort of text content in addition to the icon. One way is to use `aria-label`. Fixing both issues: `<button onclick="datagrid.deleteRow("55")"; aria-label='delete'><i class='fa fa-trash-o' ></i></button>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re trying to inject an object into a string. The string representation is probably going to look like `[object DatabaseGrid]`, and the resulting HTML:

```
<i onclick="[object DatabaseGrid].deleteRow(1);" class='fa fa-trash-o'></i>
```

Has a syntax error in the `onclick`. This is an argument for not using inline event handlers or `innerHTML`; rather, use the DOM:

```
var i = document.createElement('i');
i.className = 'fa fa-trash-o';
i.onclick = self.deleteRow.bind(self, id);
cell.appendChild(i);
```

Comment: May I suggest using "addEventListener" instead of assigning "onclick"? (Otherwise, nice answer).

Comment: @Michael: I would be curious to know why. I used to use `addEventListener` almost everywhere, but since HTML5’s been standardized, wherever I need only one handler, I’ve been more comfortable using the `on*` form; it’s a little more concise and works on extremely old browsers (`attachEvent`, anyone?).

Comment: because you never know when some other code is going to temporarily add/remove additional listeners.

Comment: @Michael: As long as they’re using the `addEventListener`/`removeEventListener` interface for the additional listeners, the `onclick` will remain working. I think `onclick` is suitable for use when there’s one clear ‘owner’ of the interactions on that element, and I think such a case applies here.

Comment: I'm quite new to Javascript. May you please explain the second argument '1' in the method bind? Your solution still fails to emulate `<i onclick="datagrid.deleteRow("55")"; class='fa fa-trash-o' ></i>` and I'm trying to figure out why

Comment: @icktoofay thank you! May you please explain the arguments self and id for the method bind? I don't quite understand the jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/bind/ and how it relates to your answer provided using bind. Again, I'm quite new to programming in general. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @user2684075: I can understand the confusion. The `bind` I am using is actually not the jQuery `bind`, but rather [a different `bind` built-in to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). The way I’m using it is sort of a shortcut for `function() { self.deleteRow(id); }`; what it actually does is it fixes the value of `this` to `self` and the first argument to `id`.